# Sending coordinates via VHF Radios to Computers

Tags: coordinates

I need to send and receive coordinates in NMEA format from a VHF radio to a computer.

Any suggestions where to look in order to accomplish this task?

The transmission will occur only when the user presses the PTT button.

Answer (score 5):

In amateur (licensed) radio, this is routinely done using APRS, which you might research.  It involves an interface from the radio to the PC, including a TNC (Terminal Node Controller).  I suppose there is no reason it couldn't be adapted to non-licensed VHF frequencies.   More detail about your need would enable me to help you more.